# how to allow only specific format with data validation (hh:mm - hh:mm - shift scheduling)

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, date-time, data-validation

so basically I need a formula which allows only data in the following format:

hh:mm - hh:mm (this is for shift scheduling, so e.g. 08:00 - 16:00)

Space before and after dash  (-) is absolutely a must for me. I've been trying to do it just with custom formatting but it doesn't work and I think I need a formula for data validation.

Comment: It would be pretty complex.  You could validate with a VBA worksheet_change function.  Or, as @teylyn suggests, change your method of data entry.

Comment: You could do this with a worksheet formula, but you would need to test every character in the string for a valid value.  And, in the case of the second hour digit, a valid value would depend on the value of the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

With this requirement, the users are basically entering text, and it's very difficult to validate text entries. It would be a lot easier to use two columns instead of one. Format the columns to use the desired time format. Tell users to enter the time as "1 pm" or "13:00" or whatever is a valid time stamp for your regional settings. Then validate the columns to allow only values less than one, because that's what the number underlying a time value is: a decimal value between 0 and 1, because 1 is a day and anything less than a day is a decimal.